# How to run a program before and after system reboot in Windows using commdline?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Wanted to run a program before and after my Windows system reboot from commandline/DOS prompt and script should execute next step after shutdown command.

Like:

> Loop for 1 to 10:
>
> 1. Run my first application1/batch1 file.
> 2. Reboot system (using shutdown command)
> 3. Run my second application2/batch2 file.
>
> End Loop

We can use startup folder to run the second application, but I wanted to have a single script to do things. The script should start from the place where system got rebooted. Is there any way to do so

Comment: What research have you done before posting this question?  Did you search for anything like 'windows run program at shutdown`?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I don't want to make use of startup folder or autoexe.bat. I want to have a single batch file/ script which will do it for me. and when system reboot it should start from the next line from where it stopped before ( shutdown command). Not getting how to make thing persistent after system reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "loop" you gave makes no sense...if you are in that loop, you would never get to step 3.

You can accomplish what you want with only a scheduled task that runs at startup.

Task (pseudo code):

```
(keep state somewhere, registry, file, etc)
get count
if count < 10, 
   do stuff
      if you need to resume, code should use Count to determine what to do next...
   increment count
   reboot (shutdown/restart)
else do nothing
```

Once you have the system configured...reboot it and your code should run 10 times...

Comment: Writing into File/Registry surely resolve my persistence logic problem. Thank You for your quick help Kory! :)